# How to find the USART TTL levels of this board?

Tags: ftdi, pinout

I have [this](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f302r8.html#overview&secondary=st_all-features_sec-nav-tab) Nucelo board with [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00105823-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf) manual and need to communicate with it with PC through its one of USART peripherals which are:

`USART3_RX (CN10 pin18)`  and `USART3_TX (CN10 pin 25)`

So it seems I need an FTDI interface between the PC and the board such as:

PC ---> FTDI interface ---> Nucelo

If that is correct, I am planning to use [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/development-tool-accessories/0429307/) FTDI interface for the purpose.

But from the datasheets I cannot figure out whether they are compatible. I have seen some interfaces which have switches to set TTL level to 3.3V or 5V. So in this case, how can we be sure of the compatibility between the Nucelo and the FTDI interface TTL levels?

Comment: You don't need an additional serial-to-USB adapter (like FTDI). Instead, a COM port should appear on your PC automatically if you connect the board via a USB cable. The serial-to-USB conversion is part of the ST-Link on the smaller part of the board. In fact, an additional FTDI cable will not work unless you change some jumpers.

Comment: Not in my case. It is disabled in the frimware I need to use(and I cannot change it) so only USART3 is working. So I am not going to use USB port of the Nucleo.

Comment: If I have to use USART3, which jumpers should change?

Comment: For USART3, you don't need to change anything. The ST-Link virtual COM port is connected to USART2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the MCU I/O is connected to the header pins (sometimes via jumpers) without a level converter in between, you need to look at the MCU datasheet.

USART3 has TTa type pins for the first MCU I found, you need to verify it for your exact MCU. TTa type pins are 3.3 V tolerant, so you want to buy the 3.3 V FTDI (which is the one you linked to).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this nice catch. Btw maybe you might have an input, I couldnt figure out one thing. I use a ready firmware and it seems only USART3 is enabled. I can flash the code via STlink but cannot use USART1 and USART2. I need to use USART3 that is what the firmware for the standalone uC is expecting. But in my case since it is a board Im not sure if I have to change anything else like jumpers. I couldnt see anything specific  in the manual about using USART3 in the Nucelo board in my question.